# Overwrite WS-Adressing-Header (to and Action)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

i have to access an SOAP-service with WS-Adressing. I simply imported the WSDL i got and i try to connect. But the Service is not happy with the generated WS-Adressing Headers.

My code looks like this:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

var entpointAddr = new EndpointAddress("https://endpoint123/services");

using (var client = new DocumentManagementServicePortTypeClient(binding, entpointAddr))
{
    client.ClientCredentials?.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "123123123");

    try
    {
        var result = client.TestFunction();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {exc.Message}");
    }
}
```

This generate a Request like this:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"/>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:8123d133-c107-44cf-97be-762014fa1b83</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://endpoint123/services</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <TestFunction xmlns = "http://xmldefs...../" />
    </ s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The Server has two problems with this request:

- ***a:To*** is pointed to the Endpoint
- ***a:Action*** is empty

The ***a:To*** is pointed to the endpoint i set in my code-snippet. But the server expected the Endpoint defined in the WSDL (a ***WS:\\*** uri). How could i tell WCF to use the ***WS:\\***-Link? Or could i overwrite it manually?

I could solve the problem with the ***a:Action*** by manually adding the path in the Reference.cs, for every function i like to use, but why it is not self generated?

Comment: If you want the to address to be `ws://` then why don't you use that here: `var entpointAddr = new EndpointAddress("https://endpoint123/services");`?

Comment: Because "ws:\\company.com\service123" is nothing u could connect to.

Comment: It it utterly unclear what the problem is. If you get an exception please share that or explain better how you want your payload to be shaped.

Comment: I got "wsa:to" is missing. i test my request with SoapUI. If i replace the "https://endpoint123/services" with the "ws:\\\\" all work just fine. Actual i try to mod the request before the Send but it looks like WCF overwrite my change after :/